# difference between using this or not inside the constructor in an angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor

example...

```
class MyComponent {

myProp!: myInterface;

constructor (private myNomeServiceInstance: NomeService ) {
    
    this.myProp = myNomeServiceInstance;

    
    this.myProp = this.myNomeServiceInstance;  
  }
}
```

what is result of "this.myProp" inside my component?

Comment: Is it a quiz? Then it's off-topic on StackOverflow. Please clarify your question and explain what your actual problem is, or which part of code you cannot understand. In both cases also provide your own research evidence - e.g. "I tried compiling and running this and got error X from `tsc` and the following values logged/in debugger: Y, Z."

Comment: ok, its only a curiosity from my project. i mean, nothing changes in either case?

this.myProp = myService;
this.myProp = this.myService;